# Unicode: string literals and character literals

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to understand how I should combine `u8""` and `"\uxxxx"` syntax to get a UTF-8 encoded string. Can I use the latter inside of the former? Should I? How about `"\x"`?

I wrote this code snippet which encodes [Я](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/042f/index.htm) (`Я`) in 4 different ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "\xD0\xAF";
    std::string s2 = u8"\xD0\xAF";
    std::string s3 = "\u042F";
    std::string s4 = u8"\u042F";

    for(unsigned char c : s1)
        std::cout << std::hex << int(c) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(unsigned char c : s2)
        std::cout << std::hex << int(c) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(unsigned char c : s3)
        std::cout << std::hex << int(c) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(unsigned char c : s4)
        std::cout << std::hex << int(c) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results are confusing. Both Clang and GCC produced this:

```
d0 af 
d0 af 
d0 af 
d0 af
```

(which is great and means that I don't need to worry about it), however VS produced this:

```
d0 af 
c3 90 c2 af 
3f 
d0 af
```

So looks like the proper portable way of doing this is `std::string s4 = u8"\u042F";`. Is that correct? Is the output of my program UB or is this a bug in VS?

Comment: I can only imagine this is a bug in `VS`. Especially `s2` seems to be getting the number of characters in the string wrong, when you explicitly add only two. Maybe print out the string lengths too?

Comment: @Galik: No, `s2` is a perfectly valid interpretation of that string.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe to some but not to my reading of the standard (C++17, §15.13.3.8). It says that an `\x` prefix character must be restricted to values that fit the character type in which it appears. For `u8` that means `char`. Therefore each `\x` prefix number represents one `char` value. In this case we have `2` of them, therefore `2` chars. I am not sure how it can be read another way tbh.

Comment: Another option is to just use the actual character instead of trying to encode its codepoint/codeunit values manually: `u8"Я"` Let the compiler work out the details for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 2.3 (Character sets) of the C++ spec:

> Additionally, if the hexadecimal value for a universal-character-name outside the
>   c-char-sequence, s-char-sequence, or r-char-sequence of a character or string literal corresponds to a control
>   character (in either of the ranges 0x00–0x1F or 0x7F–0x9F, both inclusive) or to a character in the basic
>   source character set, the program is ill-formed.

which certainly applies to s3's initializer, so you get undefined behavior here.  Other than that I can't see anything wrong with the code.

In the s2 case, VS seems to be treating each of the characters as a unicode code point and encoding it individually in utf-8.  I don't see anything in the spec saying that is wrong, or right.